# how to make shared memory with specific array size?

Tags: c, linux, ipc, shared-memory

I got a question about shared memory and segmentation fault.
I thought that it would be fine to use huge size of memory.
When I checked Shmmax, i found the huge memory can be allocated.

under data is the result of $ipcs -lm

------ Shared Memory Limits --------

max number of segments = 4096

max seg size (kbytes) = 18014398509465599

max total shared memory (kbytes) = 18014398442373116

min seg size (bytes) = 1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE 40000000


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int shmid;
    void *shared_memory = (void *)0;
    shmid = shmget((key_t)1234, sizeof(float), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    if (shmid == -1)
    {
        perror("shmget failed : ");
        exit(0);
    }

    shared_memory = (float *)shmat(shmid, NULL, 0);
    if (shared_memory == (void *)-1)
    {
        perror("shmat failed : ");
        exit(0);
    }

    static float *testx;
    testx = (float *)shared_memory;

    int k = 0;
    for(k;k<400;k++){
        testx[k] = 1.12;
    }
    for(k;k<40000000;k++){
        testx[k] = 1.12;
    }
}
```

the program can run the first for loop which has small amount of size

the problem, however, is the second loop with 40,000,000 size

any suggestion what should i edit to run this code?

Comment: You are allocating space for 1 float but are trying to write to 40,000,000 floats.

Comment: To obtain shared memory segments, consider using `shm_open`, `truncate` and `mmap` if your system has them. These are much easier to set up.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for your `SEGFAULT` is that you haven't created enough size segment with `shmget`.

The argument you passed to `shmget` as size is `sizeof(float)` which is just enough to store 1 float.

What you need to do is call shmget like this -

```
shmget((key_t)1234, sizeof(float)*40000000, IPC_CREAT|0666);
```

Then you can use all the memory correctly.

The reason that the smaller loop of 400 worked is because `shmget` creates segments that are multiple of `PAGE_SIZE`.

So even when you passed `sizeof(float)`, it allocated atleast 1 page which was enough to hold 400 floats but not 40000000.

I hope that clears the confusion.

Comment: thanks for comment. But, in this case, I got a problem with getting 'shmid' which resulted from shmget function, after editing the code.

Comment: So you get -1 from `shmget`?

Comment: For solving this problem, I had to edit shmget function like shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, sizeof(float)*40000000, ...). I guess that there is a trick relationship between input key and the way of memory managing for kernel.

Comment: yes, I got -1 from shmget before I change (key_t)1234 to IPC_PRIVATE

Comment: @Gabriel722 I was suspicious of the key 1234 to begin with.

Comment: yeap, I think that too. When I checked shm by $ipcs -m, I got 0x 4d2 which means 1234 in degit. As I tried to edit code and complile and edit and compile so on.. I missed to get back shared memory. Thanks for advising Ajay. Happy Easter!

Comment: Glad I could help!